# How do I call a Controller method in php Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Controller and in it I have a several methods. My question is How do I set the Controller's action to my form:

```
<form action="action('ExamenController@InsertUser')" method="post">
```

Obviously this give the famous exception:

Action App\Http\Controllers\ExamenController@InsertUser not defined....blablabla

Also a tried with this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{action('ExamenController@InsertUser')}}">Save</a>
```

The same error. Do anyone know how this works????
I don't understand Documentation from Laravel 5.5

But I know this works putting in web.php (previously route.php) using:

```
Route::post('url','ExamenController@InsertUser');
```

Comment: Why don't you use named routes?

Comment: How does it works? I understand nothing from laravel documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is to do it like so:

```
<form action="{{ action('ExamenController@InsertUser') }}" method="post">
```

This is well outlined in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-controller-actions).

This error, though:

> Action App\Http\Controllers\ExamenController@InsertUser

Says that the method does not actually exist inside your controller.

Yes, you have defined a route for it with `Route::post('url','ExamenController@InsertUser');`, but have you actually created this method inside your `ExamenController` yet?

The error suggests you haven't and so I would double check that it exists and/or is spelt correctly.

An alternative, although this won't solve the issue if the `InsertUser` method doesn't exist would be to achieve what you're after like this:

```
<form action="{{ url('url') }}" method="post">
```

If you wanted to do this using named routes, then you can do this by providing a name to the route and then using that for your form action:

```
Route::post('url','ExamenController@InsertUser')->name('InsertUser');

<form action="{{ route('InsertUser') }}" method="post">
```

Which, again, is outlined in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls#urls-for-named-routes).

Comment: Please post your controller in your question.

Comment: public function InsertUser(Request $request)
    {
     DB::table('usuarios')->insert([.......

Comment: Hector, add it to your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Nice, the last one works, using names. Guys sorry but I'm Naive programmer

Answer (score 0):

While using blade to merge in the route or url is handy, Laravel has a built-in way to handle this:

```
{!! Form::model($form, ['id' => 'my_form_id', 'method' => 'POST', 
'action' => ['ExamenController@InsertUser', $form->id], 'class' => 'some-class'])!!}
```

Comment: Really? I didn't know about this. I will try it.